# ASP.NET core Web API: Authorization based on permissions from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I am looking for a solution/suggestion that helps me creating permission based access to web api endpoints/controller actions.

Role based access is not suitable becuase I don't have fixed rules that I could use in code like Role("Admin") oder Role("Controller").

Claim based permissions is also not feasable because each user/client can have different permissions on each business object/entity (e.g. Read/Write-access to own tickets and read access to all ticket of his/her company or if its a technician of my company full access to all tickets of all customers. So each user would have 10s or even hundrets of claims which I would have to evaluate at each access of my API.

It is some kind of multi tenancy in just on database and the tenants are our customers with some kind of "master tenant" that has access to all of the tenant data.

I think that something like Visual Guard would satisfy my needs but it is pretty expensive and they don't support net core for now and their documentation seems pretty outdated.

I don't need a usable solution at once but some hints and tricks how I could achieve that would very much be apprieciated because I am looking and searching for some time now.

**Details on "database permissions":**
What I mean is in my frontend (Winforms app) I want to establish a security system where I can create and assign roles to users and in those roles is defined which actions a user can execute and which CRUD operations he/she can do on specific business objects. Each role can have n users and each role can have n permissions. Each permission on itself declares for exmaple Create:false, Read:true, Write:true and Delete:false. If a permission for a specific business object is not found CRUDs on that BO is denied totally.

So whenever an action in my API is called I have to check if that user and his/her rule allows him to do that specific action based on rules and permissions in my database.

**Details an application structure:**
Frontend will be a Winforms app which calls the API in the background by OData. I don't want to rely solely on security in the Winforms app because the API will be accessible from the internet and I can't be sure if a user would not try to access the api with his credentials just to see what is possblie without the "frontend filter". So the permissions lie in the API and if a user tries to access s.t. in the frontend app the app itself "asks" the API if that is possible.
Later on I want to create mobile clients that also use the Odata Web API.

Comment: Did you already checkout the [Identity Server Project](https://identityserver.io/)?

Comment: I put some more detail into my question. IdentityServer does not support permissions based on database entries it seems.

Comment: Their Policy Server seems to do what I want but this is also pretty pricey and so not a real solution since my application will just be used by 3 persons in the beginning.

Comment: "create and assign roles to users and in those roles is defined which actions a user can execute"

so you have roles and have users asigned to those specific roles, i thing this can help you a lot

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/01/08/aspnet-core-22-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example-api

Comment: No thats not what I want. At the time I write my code the roles and users don't even exist. It is not even clear which roles will have access to which action or controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant API in asp.net core are:

- IAuthorizationService
- AuthorizationPolicy
- IAuhtorizationRequirement
- IAuthorizationHandler

The authorization pattern you are looking for is called Resource-based authorization

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Basically, you can define AuthorizationPolicy, and apply it to a instance of a resource:

```
var ticket = _ticketRepository.Find(ticketID);

var authorizationResult = await _authorizationService
        .AuthorizeAsync(User, ticket, "EditTicketPolicy");
```

In the authorization handler, you can check if the user is the owner of the resource.

```
public class ResourceOwnerRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}

public class ResourceOwnerHandler 
    : AuthorizationHandler<ResourceOwnerRequirement, MyBusinessObject>
    //: AuthorizationHandler<ResourceOwnerRequirement> use this overload to handle all types of resources...
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context, 
        ResourceOwnerRequirement requirement, 
        MyBusinessObject resource)
    {
        int createdByUserId = resource.CreatedBy;
        Claim userIdClaim = ((ClaimsIdentity)context.User.Identity).FindFirst("UserId");

        if (int.TryParse(userIdClaim.Value, out int userId)
            && createdByUserId == userId)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
    }
}

//admin can do anything
public class AdminRequirementHandler : IAuthorizationHandler
{
    public Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        if (context.User.Claims.Any(c => c.Type == "Role" && c.Value == "Administator"))
        {
            while (context.PendingRequirements.Any())
            {
                context.Succeed(context.PendingRequirements.First());
            }
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

BTW, this still can be called claims or role based authorization. Users with specific role can edit their own tickets, but users with admin role also other tickets. The difference is that you apply authorization to a resource, not just action

EDIT:

Comment: Okay, I already looked into that and it would mean that I would have to write an authorizationhandler for each of my business objects but I think that would be feasable... I will look into that! Thanks!!!

Comment: Ah I see, and in HandleRequirementAsync I would realize my database calls to see if the user has actually the right to do what he/she wants. Nice!

Comment: Not necessarily, the API gives you oportunity to write more generic auhtorization handlers, e. g. one handler to handle all your business object.. It's completely up to you

Comment: *"see if the user has actually the right to do what he/she wants"* - actually, that's not recommended. Permissions should be already present in form of claims in the user's identity and you can fill the claims based on your database in your IClaimsTransformer implementation. I recommend that your handlers works only with the record and claims

Comment: Okay, but that would mean that if I have lets say 30 business classes with different combinations of permissions that I could have really many claims.

Comment: After some thinking: since Claims are "just" key/value-Pairs and I could encode them in any way I want: Key "Ticket", Value "CRUD", Key "Customer", Value: "RU". Since that data is saved in a cookie which could be tempered with, I would use Sessions or is there a more robust and secure way?

Comment: It is not good idea to store such claims in cookie or session. Basically, in cookie you should store minimum info, such us User identificator. ASP.NET Core provides API that will fill the rest of the claims in each request, see ClaimsTransformer, see https://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/claims-transformation-and-authorization-policy-in-aspnet5-mvc6

Comment: Thanks man! About ClaimTransformer: I've already learned that the ClaimsTransformer "fills" the User/Principal with every claim I need/want and so I don't have to care about payload size and insecure client storage (Cookies).